# Sending sms via amazon tollfree number using pinpoint Nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, aws-pinpoint

Hey everyone so I am trying to send an SMS message via amazon pinpoint using a toll-free number via nodejs. Note the numbers in this code have been changed for security. Heres my code:

```
router.get("/send-text", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const sender = "+18446850251";
    const destinationNumber = "+14325948991";
    const message = "HELLO from AWS";
    const applicationId = "myApplicationId";
    const messageType = "TRANSACTIONAL";
    AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });
    const pinpoint = new AWS.Pinpoint();
    const params = {
      ApplicationId: applicationId,
      MessageRequest: {
        Addresses: {
          [destinationNumber]: {
            BodyOverride: message,
            ChannelType: "SMS"
          }
        },
        MessageConfiguration: {
          SMSMessage: {
            Body: message,
            MessageType: messageType,
            OriginationNumber: sender
          }
        }
      }
    };
    const result = await pinpoint.sendMessages(params).promise();
    res.send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Upon running this code I get the following response:

```
{
MessageResponse: {
ApplicationId: "myApplicationId",
RequestId: "8beaebf0-f33a-42d3-bb88-1f3efcf493eb",
Result: {
+14325948991: {
DeliveryStatus: "PERMANENT_FAILURE",
StatusCode: 404,
StatusMessage: "Resource not found"
}
}
}
}
```

Side note: the reason I am doing this is that I received an email from AWS and my understanding is that I can no longer send text messages via the application to a person (a 10 digit long code) via SNS topics and must send them via pinpoint using a 10DLC long code or toll-free number starting June 1st is that correct?

[image of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9VaY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNS messaging was not explicitly enabled. Make sure you double-check this setting

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct as stated in this AWS document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-awssupport-long-code.html

I just tested this using these values:

```
    String message = "This is a Pinpoint test"; 
    String appId = "2fdc4442c6a2483f85eaf7a9430xxxxx";
    String originationNumber = "+14387956xxx" ;
    String destinationNumber = "+18195765xxx" ; 
    System.out.println("Sending a message" );
```

Response was:

**+18195765xxx:MessageResult(DeliveryStatus=SUCCESSFUL, MessageId=4eniddp3gqrsarku8q2i2vnqqo0v8eov0t1dhs80, StatusCode=200, StatusMessage=MessageId:**

The app id can be obtained from the AWS Management Console:

[image]

To get the origination number - you request a code in the AWS Console and use that in your app logic:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, still having trouble sending a message via pinpoint. Any ideas?

Comment: When you send a message, you need a valid origination number. Can you confirm that is correct.

Comment: I registered a toll-free number via pinpoint and copied and pasted it into the sender variable. So yes if that's what you mean then it's correct.

Comment: check your app id too - i just tested - see code above and got a 200 response

Comment: can I see a code snippet? the app id is the Project ID next to your Project name under pinpoint > all projects correct?

Comment: Yes - i modified my response above

Comment: Strange I copied and pasted mine directly. Can I by chance see a code snipet?

Comment: JS Code snippet here -- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascriptv3/example_code/pinpoint/src/pinpoint_send_sms_message.ts

Comment: Did you have to register a company or anything? I just gave a project name and it provided me with a company id and I configured the code as shown above

Comment: You need to request a code in the AWS Console and use that in your application logic as the origination number. Make sure the code is Enabled - as shown in the screen shot above

Comment: Could my problem be that I am using toll free instead of long code? See attached screenshot

Comment: Try testing with Long code and then send to mobile number where you can verify.